# Interchanging limits and integrals

Tags: integration, analysis, limits, functions

Can I interchange the limit and integral of this function:

$$f_n(x) = \frac{1 + \cos x(\sin x)^n}{(n + 1)^2}$$ with  integration over $[a,b] = \left[0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$

How is this done? I don't understand the theory behind this, and looking at examples has not made it clear how to approach these problems.
So how do I solve this ?

Comment: Do you need the definite integral of $f(x)$ from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$?

Answer (score 0):

The interchange of the limits in this case means that $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}f_n(x)dx \stackrel{?}{=} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x)dx$$Interchanging this limit (i.e. having the right-hand side equal the left-hand side), is valid if $f_n(x)$ is a uniformly convergent sequence of continuous real-valued function on $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$. Try to show that this is the case.

Comment: what is the limit of (sin(x))^n ?

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\int\frac{1+\cos(x)\sin^n(x)}{(1+n)^2}\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\frac{1}{(1+n)^2}\int\left(1+\cos(x)\sin^n(x)\right)\space\text{d}x=$$
$$\frac{1}{(1+n)^2}\left(\int 1\space\text{d}x+\int\cos(x)\sin^n(x)\space\text{d}x\right)=$$
$$\frac{1}{(1+n)^2}\left(x+\int\cos(x)\sin^n(x)\space\text{d}x\right)=$$

---

Substitute $u=\sin(x)$ and $\text{d}u=\cos(x)\space\text{d}x$:

---

$$\frac{1}{(1+n)^2}\left(x+\int u^n\space\text{d}u\right)=$$
$$\frac{1}{(1+n)^2}\left(x+\frac{u^{n+1}}{n+1}\right)+\text{C}=$$
$$\frac{1}{(1+n)^2}\left(x+\frac{\sin^{n+1}(x)}{n+1}\right)+\text{C}=$$
$$\frac{nx+x+\sin^{n+1}(x)}{(n+1)^3}+\text{C}$$

---

And notice that:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sin^n(x)=0\space\space\space\text{for}\space x\in\mathbb{R}$$